# Postgis points inside and outside polygons

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I m trying to figure out how to detect cars that enter into an area and leave this  area.
Currently, I have a table that contains car Id, timestamp, latitude,longitude (carid, timestamp,lat,lon) (the data comes from GPS trackers).
I have polygon variable that I convert into a geometry type.

My goal is to say
Car A in at 8am, Car A out at 9am, Car A in a 3pm, Car A out at 4pm, Car B in a 10am, Car B out at 3pm, ...

I know how to find points (lat/lon) inside a polygon with ST_Within and outside using ST_Disjoint.

From this, I suppose I have to find the closest inside and outside points to the polygon for each car (if the timestamp of the outside point

But I can't figure out how to write the right query knowing a car can enter/exit several times per day.

Comment: Could you provide: some test data, the query you've written so far, and a create table statement? It always significantly improves the chances that somebody answers your question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The brute force approach is to periodically ask the status (in/out) of each car.

```
SELECT carID, st_within(car_geom, boxgeom) AS in_box FROM table 
WHERE timestamp = '2018-06-05 09:00:00';
```

This gives you a list of car IDS and `True` if in, `False` if out. However it assumes that your data has one and only one point recorded every second.

In practice I would look for `timestamp BETWEEN '2018-06-05 09:00:00' AND '2018-06-05 09:01:00'` and ensure that you only get one row for each car by using `GROUP BY carID`. You will need to use an aggregate function around your st_within. Use `bool_and` if you want in_box to be True only if all of the points are inside the box; use `bool_or` if you want in_box to be True if at least one of the points is inside.

```
SELECT carID, bool_or(st_within(car_geom, boxgeom)) AS in_box 
FROM table WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2018-06-05 09:00:00' 
AND '2018-06-05 09:01:00' GROUP BY carID;
```

I would then use some python to generate the queries and analyse the results (eg using psycopg2).

There is probably a more elegant solution.